# Spark: subset a few columns and remove null rows

Tags: apache-spark

I am running spark 2.1 on windows 10, I have fetched data from MySQL to spark using JDBC and the table looks like this

```
x      y       z
------------------
1      a       d1
Null   v       ed
5      Null    Null
7      s       Null
Null   bd      Null
```

I want to create a new spark dataset with only `x and y columns` from the above table and I wan't to keep only those rows which do not have null in either of those 2 columns. My resultant table should look like this

```
x      y
--------
1      a
7      s
```

The following is the code:

```
val load_DF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://100.150.200.250:3306").option("dbtable", "schema.table_name").option("user", "uname1").option("password", "Pass1").load()
val filter_DF = load_DF.select($"x".isNotNull,$"y".isNotNull).rdd
// lets print first 5 values of filter_DF
filter_DF.take(5)
res0: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([true,true], [false,true], [true,false], [true,true], [false,true])
```

As shown, the above result doesn't give me actual values but it returns Boolean values (true when value is not Null and false when value is Null)

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
val load_DF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://100.150.200.250:3306").option("dbtable", "schema.table_name").option("user", "uname1").option("password", "Pass1").load()
```

Now;

```
load_DF.select($"x",$"y").filter("x !== null").filter("y !== null")
```

Comment: Thanks, It runs without any error but there is no data in the output. It displayed a blank table. I also tried with a single filter like this `load_DF.select($"x",$"y").filter("x != null")` but no luck.

Comment: try load_DF.select($"x",$"y").filter("x != Null")

Answer (score 2):

Spark provides [DataFrameNaFunctions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameNaFunctions.html) for this purpose of dropping null values, etc.

In your example above you just need to call the following on a [DataSet](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html) that you load

```
val noNullValues = load_DF.na.drop("all", Seq("x", "y"))
```

This will drop records where nulls occur in either field `x` or `y` but not `z`. You can read up on `DataFrameNaFunctions` for further options to fill in data, or translate values if required.

Comment: Basing on your answer, this worked for me `val filter_DF = load_DF.select($"x",$"y").na.drop().rdd`

Comment: Check my updated answer, which specifies to drop only `x and y` now explicitly. My original answer would have dropped records where `z == null ` which is not what you asked for

Answer (score 1):

Apply "any" in na.drop:

```
df = df.select("x", "y")
       .na.drop("any", Seq("x", "y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply applying a function (in this case `isNotNull`) to the values when you do a `select` - instead you need to replace `select` with `filter`.

```
val filter_DF = load_DF.filter($"x".isNotNull && $"y".isNotNull)
```

or if you prefer:

```
val filter_DF = load_DF.filter($"x".isNotNull).filter($"y".isNotNull)
```